# Chrome: why are margins/paddings missing when an html is served from a web server vs loaded from file?

Tags: html, css

Is there any special css automatically added when an html file is loaded from local filesystem? The exact html is displayed slightly differently when loaded dynamically from a webserver. See the screenshots:

From a local file stored in a local disk and opened in Chrome:

[image]

The same content loaded from a web server in Chrome:

[image]

I am trying to get the html displayed as in the local file, i.e. with margins and paddings. I know that I can add css style, but I'm curious to know why these two are displayed differently.

Using this html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p><strong><span>TEST1</span></strong></p>
    <p><strong>Test2</strong></p>
    <p>testparagraph.</p>
</div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: When you say from a local file, do you mean you are clicking the file? Or a local server? If just loading the file, I would suspect what you seeing is a different interpretation of line breaks by your OS vs a server OS you might otherwise use.

Comment: Stored a file in a local disk and opened the file in Chrome.

Comment: lots of behavior is different when using the `file:///` protocol vs `http...`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WB9yVtc — I can't reproduce the problem. Likely this is a configuration issue with your browser. Maybe an extension or some user CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for checking out. In incognito mode it works fine, likely caused by some extension or plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tested in incognito mode in Chrome, everything seems to work fine. This is likely caused by some kind of extension.